# import node_modules library failed

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, node-modules

i am working on an angular project and facing a tricky problem, it has been some hours now and it's a maze, i really can't see where is the problem.
i installed a A library in my project, this library depends on a B library.
in my node_modules, i have the two folders, and  in each, the .js file corresponding to each library.

in the .js of A, import'node_modules/libs/b/lib.min.js' fails during build, although the file exists.
i have an image that explains it very simply[image: import transitive library]